# 3 Table into 1 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, relationship

Let's say we have 3 tables for `contents`, `galleries`, `questions` and one thable for `comments` like this:

```
**Contents**
--------------
ContentID | Title | Body

**Galleries**
--------------
GalleryID | Title | Rank

**Questions**
-------------
QuestionID | Title | Body | SendDate

**Comments**
------------
CommentID | Name | Body | ContentID | GalleryID | QuestionID
```

What is a standard way to connect `Comments` table to other 3 tables? Is it right way to use other three table's foreign keys inside `Comments` table?

Comment: Looking at the answers it should be clear that you need to clarify exactly how your system works. Is a comment specific to only one other table? Is it specific to all three as a combination?

Comment: @Tom: Each comment specific to a special table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right, but it's better to have a Commentable Table, from which other 3 tables inherit. something like this:

```
Commentable(CID, title)
```

All contents, galleries and questions , first should be inserted in Commentable, then in their own tables. So other tables will be like this:

```
Contents( CID, Body)
Galleries(CID, Rank)
Questions(CID, Body, SendDate)
```

And a comment will be associated with a commentable, so

```
Comments(CommentID, Name, Body, CID)
```

and finally, if you need to specify if comment is from a gallery, question or content, you may put a field (i.e. Type) which shows the type of commentable. This way will reduce redundancy and has a more reasonable design.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the standard way of connecting tables if you want to bind a `Comments` to a `Questions` connected to a specific `Contents` in a specific `Galleries`.

But if a `Questions` regards only a specific `Contents` and a `Contents` just exists in a specific `Galleries` your model would be more like

```
Contents
--------------
ContentID
GalleryID
Title
Body


Galleries
--------------
GalleryID
Title
Rank


Questions
-------------
QuestionID
ContentID
Title
Body
SendDate


Comments
------------
CommentID
Name
Body
QuestionID
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use connector tables, but you'll need three of them:

```
Contents       ContentComments   
- ContentID    - ContentID            <-- (ContentID,CommentID) as PK, 
...            - CommentID                ContentID as FK, CommentID as FK...

Galleries      GalleryComments
- GalleryID    - GalleryID
...            - CommentID

Questions      QuestionComments
- QuestionID   - QuestionID
...            - CommentID

Comments
- CommentID
- Name
- Body
```

Comment: This is only appropriate if they are many-to-many relationships (i.e., the same comment can belong to multiple Galleries)

Comment: @Tom H. yes, of course you're right :) One Connector-table would be sufficient, or just keep the authors layout

Answer (score 0):

That is the right way if each comment is connected to one content item, one gallery item and one question.

If each comment is only connected to either a content item, a gallery item or a question, you should use three tables to connect them, like Matten showed.